# What is the correct way to set timeouts in s3fs.S3FileSystem?

Tags: python, timeout, dask, python-s3fs

I've tried various ways to set the read timeout on a `s3fs.S3FileSystem` object such as

`s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(s3_additional_kwargs={"read_timeout": 500}, config_kwargs={"read_timeout": 500} )`

or
`s3.read_timeout = 500`
But none of them seem to be controlling the timeout as expected. Does anyone know of the correct way to set these types of parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
S3FileSystem.read_timeout = 500
```

would work *before* the creation of any instance, since it controls the default timeout applied to instances.

If you want to set it per-instance, you need `config_kwargs` (passed to botocore's [`Config`](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html#botocore.config.Config)). It seems you tried this version, so it's worth following up with aiobotocore to see if their proxy AioConfig supports the argument.

Note that there are other timeouts such as `connect_timeout` and lower-level HTTP/socket things that you might be hitting.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this - I think I was setting it after the creation of the instance.  That was probably my error.  Let me check if it works setting it before instance creation.